# Cornice schema validation with colanderalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, colanderalchemy, cornice

Cornice's [documentation](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#using-colander) mentions how to validate your schema using a colander's `MappingSchema` subclass. How should we use a colanderalchemy schema for the same purpose? Because if we create a schema using colanderalchemy as stated in the [documentation](http://colanderalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deform.html#examples-using-colanderalchemy-with-deform), the schema object has already instantiated the colander's class, and I think that this results in an error.

To be more precise, here is my sample code:

```python
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from cornice.resource import resource, view
from colanderalchemy import SQLAlchemySchemaNode
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Unicode,
    )

Base = declarative_base()

'''
SQLAlchemy part
'''

class DBTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,
                info={'colanderalchemy': {'exclude': True}})
    name = Column(Unicode(70), nullable=False)
    description = Column(Unicode(256))


'''
ColanderAlchemy part
'''

ClndrTable = SQLAlchemySchemaNode(DBTable)


'''
Cornice part
'''

PRF='api'

@resource(collection_path='%s/' % PRF, path='%s/{fid}' % PRF)
class TableApi(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view(schema=ClndrTable, renderer='json')
    def put(self):
        # do my stuff here
        pass
```

Where `ClndrTable` is my auto-generated schema. Now, when trying to deploy this code, I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Schema node construction without a typ argument or a schema_type() callable present on the node class
```

As I've mentioned earlier, I am suspecting that the problem is that `ClndrTable` (given as an argument to the `view` decorator) is an instantiation of the automatically generated schema by colanderalchemy.

Anyone knowing how to resolve this?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to the issue of colander having both a `typ` property and a `schema_type` property.  They're both supposed to tell you the schema's type, but they can actually be different values.  I [filed an issue with colander](https://github.com/Pylons/colander/issues/229), but if there's a fix it'll likely not make it to pypi any time soon.

So what's happing is: ColanderAlchemy ignores `schema_type` and uses `typ` while Cornice ignores `typ` and uses `schema_type`.

You can hack a fix with the following: `ClndrTable.schema_type = lambda: ClndrTable.typ`

However, that just leads you to the next exception:

```
cornice.schemas.SchemaError: schema is not a MappingSchema: <class 'colanderalchemy.schema.SQLAlchemySchemaNode'>
```

This is due to Cornice not duck typing but expecting all Schema to be a subclass of MappingSchema.  However, MappingSchema is just a Schema with typ/schema_type being Mapping (which is what ColanderAlchemy returns).

I'll see if I can enact some changes to fix this.

### Update

Despite the names, 'typ' and 'schema_type' have two different purposes.  'typ' always tells you the type of a schema *instance*.  'schema_type' is a method that's called to give a SchemaNode a default type when it's instantiated (so it's called in the `__init__` if you don't pass a `typ` in, but other than that it's not supposed to be used).

Cornice has been patched to properly use `typ` now (though, as of this message, it's not part of the latest release).

Comment: OK, I didn't know it was a bug, I hoped it was a problem of me having misunderstood something. I saw your report on colander site, do you think an answer can be found in this?

Comment: I filed a path to cornice to fix this issue:  https://github.com/mozilla-services/cornice/pull/309  If that's accepted then you'll have to either use a copy from the github repo or wait for the patch to be released into a regular release.

Comment: Tim, that's great. I'll periodically check the status of your commit and see if it's accepted (meaning it doesn't break anything else). If so, I'll pass the changes into my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The patch has been merged, so you can use the github repo now with ColanderAlchemy.

Comment: Cool! I'll use it to see how it goes. Thanks again!